# VBA replace multiple strings from a separate list

Tags: vba, excel

I need to replace STRINGS but so far I managed to replace words only. The code is going through Description column and is supposed to replace every sequence from the list. 
The idea is to use abbreviations(*new values*) rather than complete words (*old values*).

Every time there is a neighboring (no space) word,character etc, the code fails. What is wrong? Thank you!!!

```
Sub ReplaceWords_BUT_Need_ToReplaceStrings()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'This macro works with separated words only. Eliminate hyphens etc before applying this macro.

    Dim r As Range, A As Range
    Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet, LastRow As Integer, v As String, j As Integer,      
    oldv As String, newv As String

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row

    Set s1 = Sheets("JE_data")
    Set s2 = Sheets("ListToReplace")
    Set A = s1.Range("J:J").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    For Each r In A
        v = r.Value

        For j = 2 To LastRow

            oldv = s2.Cells(j, 1).text
            newv = s2.Cells(j, 2).text
```

'Replace function as you've used it is case sensitive.
  'Are you sure that all your invoice words start with capital letter?
  'If not then use v = Replace(v, oldv, newv, 1, -1, vbTextCompare) function instead. OK.

```
        v = Replace(v, oldv, newv, 1, -1, vbTextCompare)    
        'v = Replace(v, oldv, newv)

        Next j
        r.Value = Trim(v)

    Next r

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Example:

*ListToReplace*

```
Left column (old)     Right column (new)
----------------------------------------
Invoice               inv 
Salary                sy 
Credit                cr
```

*JE_data*

```
cr Note
cr note 
INV/2712/14RF/0229/14 
Invoice 1078 10 
TECHNOQ01SI 2014 03288
```

(**Editor note:** I don't know if the example is correct since it was written in the comments)

`Credit` was replaced with `cr` and `Invoice` was expected to be replaced with `inv` but it was not

Comment: Can you just add an example of *what you have* and one of *what you want* ? because it's not cristal clear here ...

Comment: What do you mean when you say "fails"? Do you have wrong results or do you get an error (if so, where?)

Comment: There is an excerpt from a table s2 = Sheets("ListToReplace"):

Comment: Left column (old)  Right column (new)

Comment: Invoice inv
Salary sy
Credit cr

Comment: fails=the text in target range is NOT replaced with the New text

Comment: Description column (JE_data, column "J:J")                           cr Note cr note  INV/2712/14RF/0229/14
Invoice 1078 10 TECHNOQ01SI 2014 03288

Comment: Credit was replaced with cr

Comment: Invoice was expected to be replaced with inv but it was not...

Comment: 1./ You shoud have edited your post instead of putting th exemple in the comments, so other people may help more easily   2./ You should add some Debug.Print or just use debug mode to check the values during the execution

Comment: I agree, thank you for the comment. I will take it into account next time.

Comment: Thank you for editing examples. INV/2712/14RF/0229/14 should be on the same line with cr note.

Comment: TECHNOQ01SI 2014 03288 is on the same line with Invoice...

Comment: Replace function as you've used it is case sensitive. Are you sure that all your invoice words start with capital letter? If not then use  v = Replace(v, oldv, newv, 1, -1, vbTextCompare) function instead. Try it please and let us know if it helps.

Comment: It works perfectly!!! I double-check all possible scenarios (Non-Capital, (non)separated from other words. Thank you so much!!! The case is closed.

Comment: @Maco: you should copy your comment into an answer so that Russ1969 can accept it..

Comment: It's a great idea. I have added you comment to my original post. Should I remove it just to avoid confusion? Once again thank you VERY much!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace function as you've used it is case sensitive. Are you sure that all your invoice words start with capital letter? If not then use

```
v = Replace(v, oldv, newv, 1, -1, vbTextCompare)
```

function instead.